# How to fix async code inside loop to run program in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, callback

Code below-console log **false** but I want it to be **true**
How to make an async code run first and use the iterated value after the loop

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
let total = 0;

for (let a of arr) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (a === 1) {
      total++;
    }
  }, 1000);
}



if (total === 4) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: loop is your enemy in async node. Use map instead to transform it into a list of Promises and then use Promise.all(your_promise_collection).then(). Note that your setTimeout logic isn't a promise

Comment: can you tell me where did i go wrong here??

Comment: const arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
let total = 0

const arrPromises = arr.map(a=>{
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
     `if (a === 1) {
        total++
        res()
      } 
    }, 1000);
   
  })

})
Promise.all(arrPromises).then(result=>{
  console.log(result)
   if (total === 4) {
    console.log('true');
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous and non-blocking, your `for` loop just sets a bunch of timers and then immediately runs the code that checks the `total` before any of the timers have fired and thus before any of the timers have incremented the `total` value.

To fix, you can change the timeout to be a promise and use `async` and `await` to run the loop sequentially:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function run() {

    const arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
    let total = 0;
    
    for (let a of arr) {
        await delay(1000);
        if (a === 1) {
            total++;
        } 
    }

    if (total === 4) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }
}

run();
```

Or, to run all the timers in parallel:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function run() {

    const arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
    let total = 0;

    await Promise.all(arr.map(a => {
        return delay(1000).then(() => {
            if (a === 1) total++;
        });
    }));
    
    if (total === 4) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }
}

run();
```